# Colour of a Nitrogen rich atmosphere containing some SO2 and NH3?

Tags: atmosphere, gas, colors

I have a world orbiting an M7 red dwarf with an atmospheric composition like this:
96% N2,
2% NH3,
1% Ar
0.5% CO2,
0.5% SO2+Others

At 0.2 bars, with an Ammonia ocean (if that changes anything)

What colour will the atmosphere be from orbit and from the ground?

I've gone online and seems that all the gases mentioned above are clear, does that mean the atmosphere would be clear?

Comment: What is the mass and luminosity of the star? While just knowing the spectral class is enough to have a vague range, it would be helpful to know the exact designation. Like, is it an M1, and M3, maybe M9? Just look on the wikipedia page and they have a list of spectral types for a Red Dwarf. If your specifications fall between two types, you can use decimals. I ask this as an M0 and M9 would bring about a very different sky colour.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean the colour of the atmosphere from the inside, or from orbit?

Comment: You can not have ammonia in an atmosphere with oxygen because they will combine to form water (ice with your temperature) and nitric oxide, and you'll also get some nitrogen dioxide and nitric acid. Also be sure to add some argon to your atmosphere, as it forms from the radioactive decay of $^{40}K$, which is one of the main sources of natural radioactive decay in rocky planets.

Comment: @NeilIyer how about this: N2: 96%, NH3: 2%, Ar: 1%, CO2: 0.5%, SO2+Others: 0.5% ?

~0.2bar

Comment: Yes that seems better.

Comment: What temperatures are there? Because at 0.2 bar in room temperature all ammonia would boil off rapidly. With lower temperatures atmosphere gets denser and becomes more visible but below -70°C ammonia freezes.

Comment: @Juraj the temperature on the surface is around -60°C to -65°C

Comment: @FoxStudios One thing, $SO_2$ (in your other 0.5%) and ammonia will combine to form red $HNSO_x$ polymers, so choose one to be in your atmosphere. That could be interesting though, having a $HNSO_x$ red polymer seafloor and ammonia oceans.

Comment: @NeilIyer is it possible to build up that amount of SO2 due to volcanic activity? Surely if there are enough volcanoes it would allow the build up of SO2 even though it reacts with NH3 to form HNSO polymers. Could this allow NH3 and SO2 to exist in the atmosphere? Or would SO2 still be in very trace amounts?

Comment: @FoxStudios Yeah it could build up but it would quickly react with the ammonia, so unless there is a *very* large amount of $SO_2$ being produced, it won't last long in the atmosphere, either making the polymers on the seafloor or just going onto land (however, this would make a cool surface for a planet!).

Answer (score 0):

As the comments point out, this atmosphere is **inherently unstable.** There would need to be some biological or chemical process on the planet that breaks apart the rapidly-formed ammonium amide sulfate/ite.

But, **since HNSOx is white, you can expect a light blue/cyan atmospheric color**, assuming the star is similar to our Sun.